# Sytax error when select distinct rows in a sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

My table has 1 row 300,000 records and a few duplicate records they don't have a primary key so i came to the conclusion i need to copy all the distinct rows in the table im using this line of code

```
select * into newtable from (select distinct tag from Tags)
```

but i keep getting a syntax error 'incorrect syntax at 'end of file', expecting as, id, quoteID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to name a subquery:

```
from (...) as SubQueryAlias
```

In your case (the `as` is usally optional, except in Oracle, where it is not allowed):

```
select * into newtable from (select distinct tag from Tags) tags
```

Comment: i get this error when i use your code Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'Tags'.

Comment: Ah, I thought the problem was with the alias, but it's just that [MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)  Try GordonLinoff's answer instead!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you would use `create table as`:

```
create table newtable as
    select distinct tag from Tags;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, either you select things, then it would simply be

```
select distinct tag from Tags
```

or you want to insert something, in which case you write

```
insert into newtable
select distinct tag from Tags
```

or, as Gordon wrote, you do a create table as select